# Java Implementing linkedlist public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, linked-list

I'm writing my own implementation of a double linked list.

I got to method `public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`

```
public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {

    if (a.length < size()) {
        T[] array = (T[]) new Object[size()];

        Node temp = head;

        int currentIndex = 0;

        while (currentIndex < size) {
            a[currentIndex] = (T) temp.data;
            currentIndex++;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }

    if (a.length > size()) {
        a[size] = null;         
    }

    Node temp = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a[i] = (T) temp.data;
        temp = temp.next;
    }

    return a;
}
```

I am testing it with

```
    List<String> list = new DoubleLinkedList<String>();

    list.add(0, ("0"));
    list.add(1, ("1"));
    list.add(2, ("2"));
    list.add(3, ("3"));
    list.add(4, ("4"));
    list.add(5, ("5"));

    String array[] = list.toArray(new String[6]);

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
```

It works when I test it with `String array[] = list.toArray(new String[6]);` or `String array[] = list.toArray(new String[7]);` or any number higher. But nothing prints out if I test with `String array[] = list.toArray(new String[5]);` or below. JUnit throws a ClassCastException.

Please help me figure this out.

Edit1: changed some irrelevant code.

Comment: `new String("0")` is equivalent to `"0"`.

Comment: Alright, but that doesn't solve the issue at hand.

Comment: That's why I posted a comment and not an answer (:

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In which line exception thrown?, what is the type of temp.data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
T[] array = (T[]) new Object[size()];
```

is wrong, because of an important difference between (say) `Foo[]` and `ArrayList<Foo>`. With `ArrayList<Foo>`, the actual instance created by `new ArrayList<Foo>()` is just an `ArrayList`; the `<Foo>` is some compiler cleverness to help you keep track of the types, but it disappears at runtime. With `new Foo[10]`, however, the actual created instance *knows* that its type is `Foo[]`. This code-snippet, for example, is perfectly valid as far as the compiler is concerned, and raises a `ClassCastException` at runtime:

```
Object[] objectArray = new Integer[10];
String[] stringArray = (String[]) objectArray;
```

whereas the analogous code with `ArrayList` would be rejected by the compiler (and, if allowed by the compiler, could not be checked at runtime).

The problem with `T[] array = (T[]) new Object[size()];`, therefore, is that `T` is not generally going to be `Object` (in your case it happens to be `String`), so a `new Object[]` is not generally going to be an instance of `T[]`.

The `ClassCastException` does not occur *at* this problematic line, because the type-erasure associated with generics means that the compiler cannot actually check the cast at this line; but instead, the compiler inserts an implicit cast at the first opportunity it gets. That is — it implicitly converts this line:

```
String array[] = list.toArray(new String[6]);
```

to this:

```
String array[] = (String[]) list.toArray(new String[6]);
```

which fails, because you've sneakily tricked `list.toArray` into constructing an `Object[]` when it had promised to return a `String[]`.

To fix this, you need to use the component-type of `a`, and create a new instance of the corresponding array type, using a tiny bit of reflection:

```
T[] array = (T[]) Array.newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), size());
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the problem. I still don't completely understand why but I'll take some time to read over your answer.

Comment: I have a follow up question. How come the `ClassCastException` only comes up when the array is the same length as the list or longer?

Comment: @hiusray: The code that you've posted is not your real code. I was able to explain the root cause of the `ClassCastException` because I could infer that from your fake code, but I think your follow-up question will require your real code. The fake code does not have quite the property you describe.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. It is the real code. I only pasted the relevant part here, but everything here is exactly the same as in the .java file.

Comment: @hiusray: Oh. In that case, you have a bunch of bugs. And the line that I focused on in my answer is *not* the real problem, because you don't actually make any use of `array`. (It's true that the declaration `T[] array = (T[]) new Object[size()];` is incorrect, but that line doesn't really *do* anything, so it doesn't matter.)